# When using SW Reveal for iOS, where is self.revealViewController() coming from?

Tags: ios

So I install the pod, setup the segues, name them sw_rear and sw_front. Inside my front view controller, I try to call self.revealViewController() as instructed by tutorials, the method doesn't exist.

I'm curious to how is that method defined, where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either instantiate an instance of `SWRevealController` as a separate controller or your "front view controller" needs to subclass `SWRevealController`.

I just took a look at the project on github and they have plenty of examples showing this.

Comment: Without using cocoapods, simply by manually downloading the code files, I don't have to instantiate anything and it works, do you know why is that? And why are you quoting front view controller? It's not a name I made up, it's a thing, that's the name used in the SWReveal library. I looked at the github page too, it has plenty of examples, but nothing specific to cocoapods.